# zoom level property doesn't work on Google Map (Wordpress Function)

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Wordpress. I want to change default zoom level on google maps API. I edited "zoom: 5" property, but nothing happens. Function:

```
 function initialize() {


 var markers = [];
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
 {
       zoom: 5,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP




 });



 var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng( -5.796453, -35.206706),
  new google.maps.LatLng( -5.796453, -35.206706));

 map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);


  (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map.fitbounds` resets the viewport and ignores the zoom property you set. I found this fiddle that simulates the `map.fitbounds` function but where the zoom isn't ignored: https://jsfiddle.net/pdnsown1/2/